# How to disable autolayout animations for a single view in iOS, Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios-autolayout, uianimation

I need to disable animations for a specific view that gets animated because of its autolayout properties.

**I cannot use this:**

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled = false
```

Because it breaks the animations of other views.

**This didn't work either:**

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us more code? Like the views you are animating and the view that you dont want animated and maybe also the animation function itself?

Comment: If you can show a visual effect of your code (current and expected) that'll help more.